# What does "to walk in" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrasal-verbs

Here is the sentence "I walk in once or twice a week, and cycle on the other days".

What does "walk in" mean?

Answer (score 1):

It means to go somewhere on foot (by walking) rather than on a bicycle, in a car or on a bus. It probably refers to work, that is, a place of employment:
I live close to the factory, so I **walk in** every day, then walk back home at night.